# Do APKs verify themselves when installed on Android?

Tags: android, apk, verify

If I install an apk like this:

```
        // Setup Android Install Activity
        Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String filename = installActionIntent.getStringExtra(APK_FILENAME_PARAM);
        File apkFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                ENVIRONMENT_DIRECTORY), DIRECTORY_NAME +"/"+filename);
        installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Install
        startActivity(installIntent);
```

Does the system verify the apk with it's manifest before installing?

Reason I'm asking is because I need to do this manually and I don't think you can use jarsigner in Android SDK.

Comment: What does "verify the apk with it's manifest" mean?

Comment: When you sign an android app there is a certificate, signature and manifest generated. This is used to verify that the app actually came from google play and that all the files in it aren't corrupted.

Comment: "This is used to to verify that the app actually came from google play" -- and your proof of this, what, exactly? After all, the same information is generated for any APK, and APKs are distributed by a wide range of means, not just the Play Store.

Comment: Google play is just an example of a store that would need to verify files that it's distributing. All you need for that is inside the META-INF folder of any apk.

Comment: "Google play is just an example of a store that would need to verify files that it's distributing" -- that has nothing to do with "verify that the app actually came from google play".

Comment: I'm sorry the syntax of my explanation is not agreeing with you. Unfortunately that's not the topic I'm interested in discussing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This -as i understand it- would not be possible. Say you SHA1 the APK and embed the hash into the manifest, changing the APK and invalidating the hash. As you must check the APK itself, a hash is not a viable self-contained option: you must use signatures with external certificates that do not change.